# missing classpath file after creating Java project in Visual Studio

Tags: java, visual-studio

I run Visual Studio Code with the Java Extension pack.  When I create a Java project there is no .classpath file. The .classpath extensions are not excluded in the settings. I get the lib and src folders and a Java.app file but no classpath. I am creating a simple project (not Maven). In every tutorial and all the documentation the create project command creates lib and src directories and a .classpath.  Any thoughts?

Thx.

Comment: The .classpath file is part of Eclipse's project metadata. If you do not use Eclipse, you do not need one.

Comment: Seems like you are creating a standalone project. Please read the comment from a thread here: [Finding the .classpath file of a standalone project in VSCode](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/618#issuecomment-646392924)